# XHTML code modifications in JSF pages not reflected until server restart

Tags: jsf, facelets, hotdeploy

I have a JSF 2.0 Web Application with MyFaces implementation. The application runs on Apache Tomcat 7. When I do any modification on `xhtml` pages while I am running or debugging the application no changes reflect to the page. I need to restart tomcat in order to test even minor xhtml modifications. This causes loose of time during development.

I guess this is a MyFaces problem, because the problem started when I switched standard JSF implementation from Mojarra to MyFaces. How can this problem be solved?

Answer (score 4):

MyFaces uses different Facelet caching algorithms than Mojarra and does it more agressively. You need to set the `javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE` context parameter in `web.xml` to `Development` to tone it down.

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
    <param-value>Development</param-value>
</context-param>
```

**Update**: since Mojarra 2.2.11, it will behave the same. So, also on Mojarra, you'd need to set `Development` stage to turn off Facelet caching. Alternatively, explicitly set the `javax.faces.FACELETS_REFRESH_PERIOD` context parameter to `0`.

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.FACELETS_REFRESH_PERIOD</param-name>
    <param-value>0</param-value>
</context-param>
```

A value of `0` means "never cache". Any negative value such as `-1` means "cache infinitely". Any positive value such as `10` represents the amount of seconds to cache.

Don't forget to re-enable caching for production. The project stage is more useful as it can also be set via JNDI instead of via `web.xml`.